# Angular pipe length result

Tags: angular, pipe

I'm using a pipe so I can filter an array by a given property. Let's say it's an id.

```
<div #objs *ngFor="let obj of (arrayOfObj | pipe : search)">
   ...
</div>
```

I also added a ViewChildren to the element that contains the array.

```
@ViewChildren("objs") objs;
```

This is the input that controls the pipe:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="search" (ngModelChange)="inputSearch()">
```

This `inputSearch()` function should simply control a number variable with the length of the filtered array every time the input value is changed:

```
inputSearch(){
    this.lengthFilteredArray = this.objs.length;
    console.log(this.objs);
}
```

Also, if I log `objs` it contains a strange result, it kinda has two different lengths (I'd need the second result, the 0): [log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnvdm.png)

Here follows the `transform()` of the pipe:

```
transform(array: Array<any>, search: string)
    {
      if (!array|| !search) {
        return array;
      }

      return array.filter(o =>
        o.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
    }
```

With this approach, I'm getting like a "delayed" result. When I type a character, I receive the desired result only after I type the next character. Example: I type "x", the `lengthFilteredArray` is 4, but the array is filtered to 0. If I erase the "x", `lengthFilteredArray` is 0 and the array is not even filtered.

I don't know if this is best approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are checking length on  `ngModelChange` in "`search` variable", by that time the `this.objs` has not finished the processing or the pipe has not returned filter operated data.

You have to check result when the pipe has returned the filter data (you don't have a event for this here) or when the ngFor has finished processing the data (you have a event for this in `this.objs.changes`)

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-items-dynamically-with-ngfor-4gqss1?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
  export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChildren('objs') objs: QueryList<any>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.objs.changes.subscribe((obj) => this.log(obj));
  }

  log = (q) => console.log(q); // in your case check q.length here not on search change
}
```

Comment: yeah that works too, I have included longer way incase you need more than lenghth.

Comment: @Kauls if I think about it directly using observer.lenght would not work as observe change would not have been fired at the correct time. so its a hit by chance, using my way in the answer will always work.

Comment: I made a mistake, somehow. This solution just seems to increment in the Length property everytime I type something in the input field.

Comment: I need to update the `lengthFilteredArray` everytime I type something accordingly with the length of the filtered array. How could I reach this?

Comment: that is exactly what this does, can you  give a stackbitz example of how you are implanting it

Comment: I'm sorry, It worked just fine! Thank you very much.
This is what worked for me:
`inputSearch(){
    this.objs.changes.subscribe((obj) => this.lengthFilteredArray = obj.length);
  }`

Comment: yes this will work.